# Загрузка MainActivity на Android

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток.

У меня такой вопрос: программа работает с nfc модулем и отправляет данные на сервер. В зависимости от полученных данных формируется вывод информации и отображение фона приложения. При включенном интернете все работает как часы... Хочу добавить чтобы при выключенном интернете (данные то он не может считать) выводилось на экран, что отсутствует подключение к интернету и проверялось подключение, как только интернет появился, сразу все подгрузилось автоматически.

Заметил, что когда интернет выключен, переменная, в которую должны быть записаны данные равняется null, поставил цикл с условием, что пока эта переменная пустая, повторяем запрос на сервер, но в таком случае у меня не загружается элементы моего приложения. То есть они ждут пока эта процедура закроется, а она зацикливается и не выходит из нее.

Также пробовал ставить условие, что если эта переменная пустая, то не запрашивать данные с сервера, а просто вывести "нет подключение", но тогда загружаются все элементы приложения (textedit, button, ...), но для получения данных нужно закрыть приложение и заново открыть, что для меня не подходит.

Подскажите, как лучше решить мою проблему? Описал все смутно, но, надеюсь, вы меня поймете:)

UPD: Запилил проверку подключения с помощью:

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //You can replace it with your name

        if (ipAddr.equals("")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

А как мне теперь сделать, чтобы он проверял эту работу, пока не появится интернет?

Comment: http://govnokod.ru/56

Comment: `MotherOfCode!`, давно я не видел такого качественного-внокода...   https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20internet%20connection%20status%20listener&es_th=1

Answer (score 1):

Для проверки подключения можно использовать следующий метод:

```
public boolean isOnline() { 
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Он требует добавления следующего пермишена:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Подробнее [тут](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)
Теперь можете использовать например `Handler`, который будет раз в определенное время проверять состояние интернета и если все ок, то загружать необходимые данные.

```
private Handler mInternetHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mInternetRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if(isOnline()){
            doInternetWork();
        } else {
            mInternetHandler.postDelayed(this, TIME_TO_CHECK_INTERNET_CONNECTION);
        }
    }
}
```

и собственно перед тем как загружать данные проверяете состояние интернет, если его нет запускаете `Handler`

```
mInternetHandler.post(mInternetRunnable);
```